# Python3 webbrowser module on raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have python3 code, that works in Windows OS, but doesn't on raspberry pi4

Maybe anybody can help?

```
import time
import os
from webbot import Browser

web = Browser()
web.go_to('https://xxxxxxx')
#time.sleep(1)
web.type('cccccccc', into = 'email')
#time.sleep(1)
web.type('dddddddd', into = 'password', id='edit-pass')
web.click('submit', id='edit-submit')
```

In windows OS this works, but on Raspberry Pi OS it is returning answer

```
  %Run eso.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/ESO/eso.py", line 5, in <module>
     web = Browser()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/webbot/webbot.py", line 66, in
__init__
     os.chmod(driverpath, 0o755) PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:  '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/webbot/drivers/chrome_linux'
```

Any things?

After trying to make changes by answer, i get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ESO $ sudo python3 eso.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eso.py", line 5, in <module>
    web = Browser()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/webbot/webbot.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/webbot/drivers/chrome_linux'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing method from webbot to selenium

Answer (score 0):

u may try using a module called `webbrowser` or
as the error says its not getting the right permition so do this :

1. open terminal
2. type " cd (where u have stored ur file)"
3. type " sudo python3 (filename).py"

thats it

Comment: ok, so now I got something like this: (check update)